# Running on low-graphics mode on upgrade to 19.10

Tags: 19.04, login-screen, amd-graphics, partial-upgrade, 19.10

I had upgraded my system from Ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10. Due to power failure, there was partial upgrade. Now when I turn on my system, it shows me an error message saying-
"Your system is running in low-graphics mode"
And after clicking on OK it goes back and shows the same message after a while.

If would be great if someone helps me get my data back as I don't have backup of it and help me recover my system ASAP.

Thanks in advance:)

SOLVED!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED!!

I used these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install gdm3
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
systemctl stop lightdm
systemctl start gdm3
```

Comment: I like this because it's recent (2020) and it solved my issue being unable to start Ubuntu when my upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 failed and I got stuck with the stated message: My fix steps were:

CTRL+ALT+F1 to go from "Low Graphics Mode" alert to Terminal.
sudo apt-get install gdm3.
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3.
[Chose gdm3].
systemctl stop lightdm.
systemctl start gdm3.

I got a gdm3 login screen. It seemed different than what I am used to. I think I have been running lightdm. I logged in.